How to find difference between two hazard ratios (ratio of hazard ratios)
I am reading a meta-analysis and in this paper the authors somehow compared HR from two groups with different treatments in each study. As I know, we can compare outcomes from two groups with different treatments via OR, RR, SMD but I don't understand how to compare two hazard ratios and find "hazard ratios ratio". Intuitively, I want to say that actually the authors represent OR on the forest plot in the study, but authors have written that it is HR on the plot. Moreover, if there is a way to compare two hazard ratios and find difference between them, especially in the Rstudio, I kindly ask you to help me understand how to perform this.

The main interest in that meta-analysis was whether a combination of chemotherapy (CT) plus supportive care (SC) is associated with longer survival than SC alone, among non-small-cell lung cancer patients who were "unsuitable for surgery or radical radiation therapy."
The hazard is the (instantaneous) risk of having an event given that you are still at risk for it. A hazard ratio (HR) is just that in principle: the ratio of the hazards between, say, two groups. It's not that dissimilar to an odds ratio in that respect, in which you calculate the odds of an event for each of two groups, and then take the ratio of those odds. Hazard ratios are more useful when the interest is in the times to events, as in the cited study.
What's different from the usual situation with an odds ratio is that a Cox proportional hazards (PH) model doesn't directly evaluate the hazards within each of the groups.* It takes advantage of the PH assumption (which implies that HRs are constant in time) to estimate directly the (log)-HRs relative to some defined reference situation. In this paper, the reference situation is SC-only patients, and the reported HR for each predictor and scenario is for CT+SC patients relative to the (reference) SC-only patients.
Standard statistical software typically contains functions for fitting Cox PH models to estimate HRs. The survival package is part of the standard distribution of R, and it comes with many helpful vignettes to show how to apply it in different use cases.

*After fitting the model you can estimate the baseline hazard over time, but that estimated baseline hazard is identically zero between event times.
